# Change Side-Menu Button/Link Text Colour Dynamically Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using a Side Menu iOS (**not my choice just by the way**) and I stumbled upon an issue that can be seen in the following image:

[image]

If you look close enough in the above figure, the red rectangle is actually highlighting the text 'Menu' that used to open the side menu and it's barely visible. It's quite simply changing the navigation bar text color which doesn't seem to affect that color.

How do I change the default color that is appearing above?

Answer (score 0):

The tint determines this color.

You can change it globally by settting

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color of the menu button in a specific ViewController . Add the following code in the method `ViewWillAppear()` of your ViewController

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
   base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
   this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(xxx,xxx,xxx);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, but this would only allow me to change the colour once, as stated above, I would like to be able to change the colour dynamically or, better put, from the PCL project through a dependancy service or something.

Comment: You want use dependancy service?

Comment: Yes I'd like to change it via a dependancy service, but if there's another better way that you might have in mind and it actually works, I wouldn't mind using that instead.

Comment: Did you use Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.forms?

Comment: For my answer below, I'm using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

NavigationPage has a property called `BarTextColor`, on iOS devices, this property changes the colour of both the navigation bar text and the menu button text. The following solution might be a problem though if one would like to have separate colours for each of the latter:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(YourPage) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(#SomeHex), BarTextColor = Color.Red};
```

**`BarTextColor = Color.Red`** produces the following output:

[image]